# how to calculate a string statement

Tags: t-sql

Given a string combination which is a calculation statement, how can I get the result, in this case is column cal in below code.
I know I can use case but is there any direct way to do the calculation?

```
    create table tl_test
    (
            cl1 int
    )

    create table tl_test2
    (
            cl1 char(1)
    )
    insert into tl_test values (21), (43), (13), (36), (41)
    insert into tl_test2 values ( '+'), ('-'), ('*'), ('/')

    select *,
    cast(c1 as varchar) + f1 
    + cast(c2 as varchar) + f2 
    + cast(c3 as varchar) + f3 
    + cast(c4 as varchar) + f4 
    + cast(c5 as varchar) as cal
    from(
    SELECT A.cl1 as c1, f1.cl1 as f1,  b.cl1 as c2,f2.cl1 as f2, C.cl1 as c3, f3.cl1 as f3, D.cl1 as c4, f4.cl1 as f4,  E.cl1 as c5
    FROM TL_TEST A
    CROSS JOIN TL_TEST2 f1
    CROSS JOIN TL_TEST B
    CROSS JOIN TL_TEST2 f2
    CROSS JOIN TL_TEST C
    CROSS JOIN TL_TEST2 f3
    CROSS JOIN TL_TEST D
    CROSS JOIN TL_TEST2 f4
    CROSS JOIN TL_TEST E
    )a
    WHERE c1 != c2
    and c1 != c3
    and c1 != c4
    and c1 != c5
    and c2 != c3
    and c2 != c4 
    and c2 != c5
    and c3 != c4
    and c3 != c5
    and c4 != c5
```

Comment: Can you at least show us the string you are trying to generate with the query above?

Comment: ok, one of them is 21*41-36/13+43

Comment: Tao Li, do you have your formulas as *ready made* strings, or are they coming from a structure like the one above (of which I do not understand the meaning at all...)?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the result of the **cal** column in a string and use [**EXEC**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) to calculate your answer.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT ' + (SELECT TOP 1 cal FROM result)
EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: The given example would be calculated with `INTs` and might return unexpectedly... In my answer you'll find an approach with dynamic SQL, but with exact (well, *float-exact*) result.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this related thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b72d0430-44ff-4ded-a3f2-04591ff32bcc/xquery-syntax-to-evaluate-math-formula?forum=transactsql), especially the answer by Erland Sommarskog.

I'm sorry, **there is no way to do this in pure *ad-hoc* T-SQL**.

#### Possible workarounds:

1) You can use dynamic SQL, which has one flaw: Your example would be calculated for `INT`s

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(100)='SELECT (' + '21*41-36 / 13+43' /*Your formula coming from somewhere*/ + ')';
EXEC(@cmd);
```

Results `902`

2) You can use XMLs implicit ability to calculate like this

```
SELECT CAST('' AS XML).value('21*41-36 div 13+43','float') 
hint: "/" must be replaced with " div "
```

Results `901.23077`

It's a pitty, that the XML type's `.value()` knows *expressions* and *values*. A value can be introduced from a table's column dynamically (`sql:column("ColumnName")`), but an expression must be a literal.

3) And you might include `.Net`-code as assembly (CLR function).

#### Conclusio

Sorry, there is no easy going...

If you need exact results you should use the XML approach in dynamically created SQL.

### UPDATE Working example

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,SomeFormula VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl(SomeFormula) VALUES
 ('1+2')
,('21*41-36/13+43')
,('(1+3)*4')
,('3.6 div (2.5-1)');

DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    SELECT 'DECLARE @x XML=CAST('''' AS XML);' +
    STUFF
    (
      (
        SELECT ' UNION ALL SELECT ' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ' AS ID, @x.value(''' + REPLACE(SomeFormula,'/',' div ') + ''',''float'')'
        FROM @tbl
        FOR XML PATH('')
      ),1,11,''
    )
);
PRINT @cmd;
EXEC (@cmd);
```

This is the generated statement

```
DECLARE @x XML=CAST('' AS XML);
          SELECT 1 AS ID, @x.value('1+2','float') 
UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS ID, @x.value('21*41-36 div 13+43','float') 
UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS ID, @x.value('(1+3)*4','float') 
UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS ID, @x.value('3.6 div (2.5-1)','float')
```

And this is the result

```
ID  
1   3
2   901,23077
3   16
4   2,4
```