# How can i calculate table values

Tags: t-sql

I have got a table. 
In this table there are some sample data.

table data:

**select col1 from table**

result set:

### col1

1+2+3+45-6+7+8-9 
1+2+3+45-6+7+89  
1+2+3+45-6+7-8+9 
1+2+3+45-6+7-8-9 
...
..
.

Is there any way to calculate column data?

Like this :

select col1, Calculate(col1) as col2 from table

col1                            col2

-----------------           -------------
1+2+3+45-6+7+8-9       51
1+2+3+45-6+7+89        141
 
1+2+3+45-6+7-8+9      53
1+2+3+45-6+7-8-9      35

Comment: Find a [comprehensive answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42268083/5089204) and read the link given there to Erland's answer...

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35302901/243373) on a similar question, requires a CLR function.

Comment: thanks @Shnugo this post is useful---> http://stackoverflow.com/a/9850919/7820095

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun

```
Declare @YourTable table (col1 varchar(100))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('1+2+3+45-6+7+8-9'), 
('1+2+3+45-6+7+89'), 
('1+2+3+45-6+7-8+9'), 
('1+2+3+45-6+7-8-9')

 Declare @SQL varchar(max) = ''
 Select @SQL = @SQL + ',('''+col1+''','+col1+')' From  @YourTable
 Select @SQL = 'Select * From (values '+Stuff(@SQL,1,1,'')+') A (col1,col2)'
 Exec(@SQL)
```

Returns

```
col1                col2
1+2+3+45-6+7+8-9    51
1+2+3+45-6+7+89     141
1+2+3+45-6+7-8+9    53
1+2+3+45-6+7-8-9    35
```